# Partition array into N chunks with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

There is this [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)
for splitting an array into chunks. Is there anyway to do this more efficiently for giant arrays using Numpy?

Comment: Are we supposed to interpret the input to this question as a [native Python array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), or a [numpy ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)? The first sentence seems to imply the former. The second sentence implies it's asking for a comparison between the former and the latter. 2-dimensional only, presumably. And when we say "efficiently... for giant arrays" are we more concerned with scaleability for asymptotically large N, regardless if it's slower for small N?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Try [`numpy.array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split).

From the documentation:

```
>>> x = np.arange(8.0)
>>> np.array_split(x, 3)
    [array([ 0.,  1.,  2.]), array([ 3.,  4.,  5.]), array([ 6.,  7.])]
```

Identical to [`numpy.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html), but won't raise an exception if the groups aren't equal length.

If number of chunks > len(array) you get blank arrays nested inside, to address that - if your split array is saved in `a`, then you can remove empty arrays by:

```
[x for x in a if x.size > 0]
```

Just save that back in `a` if you wish.

Comment: Does `np.array_split` copy the input array?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to control the split by the size of the chunk you can use:
`np.array_split(x, np.arange(chunk_size, len(x), chunk_size))`.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf, to do it with numpy, just limit the number of elements to the length of the array: `np.array_split(x, min(len(x), 3))` where 3 is the default number of groups you want.

Answer (score 28):

Just some examples on usage of [`array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split), [`split`, `hsplit` and `vsplit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
n [9]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,[4,4])

In [10]: a
Out[10]: 
array([[2, 2, 7, 1],
       [5, 0, 3, 1],
       [2, 9, 8, 8],
       [5, 7, 7, 6]])
```

Some examples on using `array_split`:
If you give an array or list as second argument you basically give the indices (before) which to 'cut'

```
# split rows into 0|1 2|3
In [4]: np.array_split(a, [1,3])
Out[4]:                                                                                                                       
[array([[2, 2, 7, 1]]),                                                                                                       
 array([[5, 0, 3, 1],                                                                                                         
       [2, 9, 8, 8]]),                                                                                                        
 array([[5, 7, 7, 6]])]

# split columns into 0| 1 2 3
In [5]: np.array_split(a, [1], axis=1)                                                                                           
Out[5]:                                                                                                                       
[array([[2],                                                                                                                  
       [5],                                                                                                                   
       [2],                                                                                                                   
       [5]]),                                                                                                                 
 array([[2, 7, 1],                                                                                                            
       [0, 3, 1],
       [9, 8, 8],
       [7, 7, 6]])]
```

An integer as second arg. specifies the number of **equal** chunks:

```
In [6]: np.array_split(a, 2, axis=1)
Out[6]: 
[array([[2, 2],
       [5, 0],
       [2, 9],
       [5, 7]]),
 array([[7, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [8, 8],
       [7, 6]])]
```

`split` works the same but raises an exception if an equal split is not possible

In addition to `array_split` you can use shortcuts `vsplit` and `hsplit`.
`vsplit` and `hsplit` are pretty much self-explanatry:

```
In [11]: np.vsplit(a, 2)
Out[11]: 
[array([[2, 2, 7, 1],
       [5, 0, 3, 1]]),
 array([[2, 9, 8, 8],
       [5, 7, 7, 6]])]

In [12]: np.hsplit(a, 2)
Out[12]: 
[array([[2, 2],
       [5, 0],
       [2, 9],
       [5, 7]]),
 array([[7, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [8, 8],
       [7, 6]])]
```

Answer (score 10):

I believe that you're looking for [`numpy.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) or possibly [`numpy.array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) if the number of sections doesn't need to divide the size of the array properly.

Answer (score 10):

Not quite an answer, but a long comment with nice formatting of code to the other (correct) answers. If you try the following, you will see that what you are getting are views of the original array, not copies, and that was not the case for the accepted answer in the question you link. Be aware of the possible side effects!

```py
>>> x = np.arange(9.0)
>>> a,b,c = np.split(x, 3)
>>> a
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> a[1] = 8
>>> a
array([ 0.,  8.,  2.])
>>> x
array([ 0.,  8.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.])
>>> def chunks(l, n):
...     """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
...     """
...     for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
...         yield l[i:i+n]
... 
>>> l = range(9)
>>> a,b,c = chunks(l, 3)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2]
>>> a[1] = 8
>>> a
[0, 8, 2]
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

np.array_split will try to split "evenly", for example, if x.shape is 10, sections is 3, you will get splits with shape [3, 3, 2, 2] instead of [3, 3, 3, 1], a workaround is using spaced indices like snippet below

```py
import math
import numpy as np


def split_evenly(x, chunk_size, axis=0):
    return np.array_split(x, math.ceil(x.shape[axis] / chunk_size), axis=axis)


def split_reminder(x, chunk_size, axis=0):
    indices = np.arange(chunk_size, x.shape[axis], chunk_size)
    return np.array_split(x, indices, axis)


x = np.arange(10)
chunk_size = 3
print([i.shape[0] for i in split_evenly(x, chunk_size, 0)])
print([i.shape[0] for i in split_reminder(x, chunk_size, 0)])
# [3, 3, 2, 2]
# [3, 3, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Here you split the array using the length you want to have.

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10,[4,4])

a
Out[27]: 
array([[1, 5, 8, 7],
       [3, 2, 4, 0],
       [7, 7, 6, 2],
       [7, 4, 3, 0]])

a[0:2,:]
Out[28]: 
array([[1, 5, 8, 7],
       [3, 2, 4, 0]])

a[2:4,:]
Out[29]: 
array([[7, 7, 6, 2],
       [7, 4, 3, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `as_strided` of numpy. I have put a spin to answer by assuming that if chunk size is not a factor of total number of rows, then rest of the rows in the last batch will be filled with zeros.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
def batch_data(test, chunk_count):
  m,n = test.shape
  S = test.itemsize
  if not chunk_count:
    chunk_count = 1
  batch_size = m//chunk_count
# Batches which can be covered fully
  test_batches = as_strided(test, shape=(chunk_count, batch_size, n), strides=(batch_size*n*S,n*S,S)).copy()
  covered = chunk_count*batch_size
  if covered < m:
    rest = test[covered:,:]
    rm, rn = rest.shape
    mismatch = batch_size - rm
    last_batch = np.vstack((rest,np.zeros((mismatch,rn)))).reshape(1,-1,n)
    return np.vstack((test_batches,last_batch))
  return test_batches
```

This is based on my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68238815/5462372.