# Split list into separate but overlapping chunks

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list `A`

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I would like to create a new list (say `B`) using the above list in the following order.

```
B = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9], [9,10,]]
```

**i.e. the first 3 numbers as `A[0,1,2]` and the second 3 numbers as `A[2,3,4]` and so on.**

I believe there is a function in `numpy` for such a kind of operation.

Comment: So by what rules do you split a list? Into groups of 3 with padding? Please be explicit.

Comment: Also see [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/312443)

Comment: Here my window size is 3., i.e each splitted list should have 3 elements  first split `[1,2,3] `and  the step size is 2 , So the second split start should start from 3rd element and 2nd split is [3,4,5] respectively.

Comment: Please add that to your question, that was *not* clear. Have you made any attempts yourself yet to solve this?

Comment: Ok I will edit my question with code I tried.

Comment: I updated the question. Will you please check it

Comment: @Rangooski The changes aren't there yet.

Comment: @Rangooski: I don't see anything. I've re-closed the question until you do update it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply use Python's built-in list comprehension with list-slicing to do this:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> size = 3
>>> step = 2
>>> A = [A[i : i + size] for i in range(0, len(A), step)]
```

This gives you what you're looking for:

```
>>> A
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9], [9, 10]]
```

But you'll have to write a couple of lines to make sure that your code doesn't break for unprecedented values of size/step.

Comment: Another list expression is `list( zip( *[x[i::2] for i in range(3)]))`.

Answer (score 12):

The 'duplicate' [Partition array into N chunks with Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406567/paritition-array-into-n-chunks-with-numpy) suggests `np.split` - that's fine for non-overlapping splits.  The example (added after the close?) overlaps, one element across each subarray.  Plus it pads with a 0.

[How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) has some good list answers, with various forms of generator or list comprehension, but at first glance I didn't see any that allow for overlaps - though with a clever use of iterators (such as `iterator.tee`) that should be possible.

We can blame this on poor question wording, but it is not a duplicate.

Working from the example and the comment:

> Here my window size is 3., i.e each splitted list should have 3 elements  first split `[1,2,3]` and  the step size is 2 , So the second split start should start from 3rd element and 2nd split is [3,4,5] respectively.

Here is an advanced solution using `as_strided`

```
In [64]: ast=np.lib.index_tricks.as_strided  # shorthand 

In [65]: A=np.arange(1,12)

In [66]: ast(A,shape=[5,3],strides=(8,4))
Out[66]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

I increased the range of `A` because I didn't want to deal with the 0 pad.

Choosing the target `shape` is easy, 5 sets of 3.  Choosing the strides requires more knowledge about striding.

```
In [69]: x.strides
Out[69]: (4,)
```

The 1d striding, or stepping from one element to the next, is 4 bytes (the length one element).  The step from one row to the next is 2 elements of the original, or 2*4 bytes.

`as_strided` produces a view.  Thus changing an element in it will affect the original, and may change overlapping values.  Add `.copy()` to make a copy; math with the strided array will also produce a copy.

Changing the strides can give non overlapping rows - but be careful about the shape - it is possible to access values outside of the original data buffer.

```
In [82]: ast(A,shape=[4,3],strides=(12,4))
Out[82]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 17]])

In [84]: ast(A,shape=[3,3],strides=(16,4))
Out[84]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

### edit

A new function gives a safer version of `as_strided`.

```
np.lib.strided_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.arange(1,10),3)[::2]
```

Comment: If you are going to re-open a question based on the comments, **at the very least** then edit the question to include that extra info. I've re-closed the question for now, as it stands it is not clear.

Comment: @Martijn I got my answer. Please open this question. It will be useful to some other people.

Comment: About the edit: it is `np.lib.stride_tricks`, you got an extra D

Answer (score 1):

This function that I wrote may help you, although it only outputs filled chunks with a length of `len_chunk`:

```py
def overlap(array, len_chunk, len_sep=1):
    """Returns a matrix of all full overlapping chunks of the input `array`, with a chunk
    length of `len_chunk` and a separation length of `len_sep`. Begins with the first full
    chunk in the array. """

    n_arrays = np.int(np.ceil((array.size - len_chunk + 1) / len_sep))

    array_matrix = np.tile(array, n_arrays).reshape(n_arrays, -1)

    columns = np.array(((len_sep*np.arange(0, n_arrays)).reshape(n_arrays, -1) + np.tile(
        np.arange(0, len_chunk), n_arrays).reshape(n_arrays, -1)), dtype=np.intp)

    rows = np.array((np.arange(n_arrays).reshape(n_arrays, -1) + np.tile(
        np.zeros(len_chunk), n_arrays).reshape(n_arrays, -1)), dtype=np.intp)
        
    return array_matrix[rows, columns]
```