# numpy stride_tricks.as_strided vs list comprehension for rolling window

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stride

When dealing with rolling windows, I wrote my functions in the way like list comprehension

```
[np.std(x[i:i+framesize]) for i in range(0, len(x)-framesize, hopsize)])]
```

Recently I discovered `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` and found it is used widely for rolling windows (for example, [this post](http://www.rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html)), even though it is a "hidden" function.

In [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6565) concerning why stride_tricks.as_strided is undocumented, it's mentioned that

> Intentionally! It's dangerous! It was just low-level plumbing to help implement broadcast_arrays().

Is there any advantage for `stride_tricks.as_strided` over the list comprehension or a for loop? I had a look at [the source code of `stride_tricks`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py) but gained little.

Comment: The recent `split` question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163366/python-split-list-in-a-specific-way may partly answer your question.  The accepted answer uses a list comprehension, my answer striding.  And I show how it can access values 'off-the-end'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085052/3293881), we can use  `strided_app` to basically get sliding views into the array and it also allows us to specify the hopsize/stepsize. Then, we simply use `np.std` along the second axis for the final output, like so -

```
np.std(strided_app(x, framesize, hopsize), axis=1)
```

Sample run for verification -

```
In [162]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(11))

In [163]: framesize = 5

In [164]: hopsize = 3

In [165]: np.array([np.std(x[i:i+framesize]) \
            for i in range(0, len(x)-framesize+1, hopsize)])
Out[165]: array([ 1.62480768,  2.05912603,  1.78885438])

In [166]: np.std(strided_app(x, framesize, hopsize), axis=1)
Out[166]: array([ 1.62480768,  2.05912603,  1.78885438])
```

Being a view into the input array, these strided operations must be really efficient. Let's find it out!

**Runtime test**

Loopy approach -

```
def loopy_app(x, framesize, hopsize):
    return [np.std(x[i:i+framesize]) \
        for i in range(0, len(x)-framesize+1, hopsize)]
```

Timings -

```
In [185]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(1001))

In [186]: framesize = 5

In [187]: hopsize = 3

In [188]: %timeit loopy_app(x, framesize, hopsize)
10 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop

In [189]: %timeit np.std(strided_app(x, framesize, hopsize), axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 111 µs per loop
```

So, to answer the question on efficiency with `strides`, the timings should help prove a point there!

Comment: Hi @Divakar  sorry I didn't make any tests done. this is an old post and I remember I used `strides` rather than list comprehension as the final solution.