# Taking subarrays from numpy array with given stride/stepsize

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Lets say I have a Python Numpy array `a`.

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

I want to create a matrix of sub sequences from this array of length 5 with stride 3. The results matrix hence will look as follows:

```
numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7,8],[7,8,9,10,11]])
```

One possible way of implementing this would be using a for-loop.

```
result_matrix = np.zeros((3, 5))
for i in range(0, len(a), 3):
  result_matrix[i] = a[i:i+5]
```

Is there a cleaner way to implement this in Numpy?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Approach #1 :**  Using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def broadcasting_app(a, L, S ):  # Window len = L, Stride len/stepsize = S
    nrows = ((a.size-L)//S)+1
    return a[S*np.arange(nrows)[:,None] + np.arange(L)]
```

**Approach #2 :** Using more efficient [`NumPy strides`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) -

```
def strided_app(a, L, S ):  # Window len = L, Stride len/stepsize = S
    nrows = ((a.size-L)//S)+1
    n = a.strides[0]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(nrows,L), strides=(S*n,n))
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: a
Out[143]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

In [144]: broadcasting_app(a, L = 5, S = 3)
Out[144]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [145]: strided_app(a, L = 5, S = 3)
Out[145]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: Thanks,
I tried this :

    X = np.arange(100)
    Y = strided_app(X, 4, 1)

Which gives Y as expected, and now :

    Z = strided_app(Y, 8, 4)# I want Z to view Y with a moving window of length 8 and step 4, but this results in junk. Can you please correct?

Comment: @volatile I am not sure what you are expecting with `Z`? Would `Z = strided_app(X, 8, 4)` give the desired `Z`? Are you expecting `Z` as 3D array instead?

Comment: Do you also get a crazy result from `strided_app(np.array([np.arange(6)]),3,1)`? I'm using python 3.6 and numpy 1.13.1 in Anaconda.

Comment: @Ziofil `strided_app` assumes 1D array. `np.array([np.arange(6)])` is a 2D array. Not sure why you need to wrap it with `np.array()` as `np.arange(6)` is already an array. What exactly are you trying to do with `np.array()`?

Comment: Nothing in particular, I noticed the overflows and I thought you might find it amusing.

Comment: I have used `as_strided` previously but found that it caused a very serious memory leak. This isn't an issue for small arrays but even using 64 GB of RAM on a server, my python programs raised MemoryError. Highly recommend using the `broadcasting_app` method.

Comment: Dude this is so automagical!. I was implementing Shi-Tomasi corner detection algo where I had to create a window for each pixel and compute something complex. This method immediately gave me all the windows!!!

Comment: as_strided is not recommended by the developers of numpy for general usage see notes here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html

Comment: @kkawabat They are simply saying that we need to be careful when using it, understanding what it does. That `writeable` flag could be added to on the safer side. Modules like `scikit-image` also [uses `as_strided`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py#L98).

Comment: @Divakar There is a line at the bottom of the reference that I linked, "For these reasons it is advisable to avoid as_strided when possible.". I guess "general usage" is vague but if a method requires care in usage it should be noted for the general audience who might stumble upon the code.

Comment: @Divakar can you please explain me the broadcasting_app part

Comment: Thank you @Divakar, your function helped quite a bit.  I'd suggest checking to ensure the ndarray is contiguous and setting the output as not writable, or you could run into problems with people modifying it.  I added an alternative solution below.

Comment: @Divakar: For the `strided_app`, is it a typo in `n = a.strides[0]`. Should it be `n = a.strides[1]`  ?

Comment: @AndyL. Well input array is 1D, so `n = a.strides[0]` is good.

Comment: ah, I missed that. I tested it on 2-D array, that's why I thought it is a typo :)

Comment: Thanks @Divakar for your comments

Answer (score 11):

Starting in `Numpy 1.20`, we can make use of the new [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view) to slide/roll over windows of elements.

And coupled with a stepping `[::3]`, it simply becomes:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

# values = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
sliding_window_view(values, window_shape = 5)[::3]
# array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
#        [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

---

where the intermediate result of the sliding is:

```
sliding_window_view(values, window_shape = 5)
# array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
#        [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
#        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
#        [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of @Divakar's code with checking to ensure that memory is contiguous and that the returned array cannot be modified.  (Variable names changed for my DSP application).

```
def frame(a, framelen, frameadv):
"""frame - Frame a 1D array
a - 1D array
framelen - Samples per frame
frameadv - Samples between starts of consecutive frames
   Set to framelen for non-overlaping consecutive frames

Modified from Divakar's 10/17/16 11:20 solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084931/taking-subarrays-from-numpy-array-with-given-stride-stepsize

CAVEATS:
Assumes array is contiguous
Output is not writable as there are multiple views on the same memory

"""

if not isinstance(a, np.ndarray) or \
   not (a.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'] or a.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS']):
    raise ValueError("Input array a must be a contiguous numpy array")

# Output
nrows = ((a.size-framelen)//frameadv)+1
oshape = (nrows, framelen)

# Size of each element in a
n = a.strides[0]

# Indexing in the new object will advance by frameadv * element size
ostrides = (frameadv*n, n)
return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=oshape,
                                       strides=ostrides, writeable=False)
```