# Python Median Filter for 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filtering, median

I have a `numpy.array` with a dimension `dim_array`. I'm looking forward to obtain a median filter like `scipy.signal.medfilt(data, window_len)`.

This in fact doesn't work with `numpy.array` may be because the dimension is `(dim_array, 1)` and not `(dim_array, )`.

How to obtain such filter?

Next, another question, how can I obtain other filter, i.e., min, max, mean?

Comment: Perhaps you just want to reshape/flatten your (N,1) array to (N,).

Comment: So maybe I have to do so:
`data = np.reshape(data, len(data))`

Comment: Better `data.flatten(order='C')`; this work!
Thanks @John Zwinck.

Now for the second question, how can I obtain these other filters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085052/3293881), we could create sliding  windows to get a `2D` array of such windows being set as rows in it. These windows would merely be views into the `data` array, so no memory consumption and thus would be pretty efficient. Then, we would simply use those `ufuncs` along each row `axis=1`.

Thus, for example `sliding-`median` could be computed like so -

```
np.median(strided_app(data, window_len,1),axis=1)
```

For the other `ufuncs`, just use the respective `ufunc` names there :  `np.min`, `np.max` &  `np.mean`. Please note this is meant to give a generic solution to use `ufunc` supported functionality.

For the best performance, one must still look into specific functions that are built for those purposes. For the four requested functions, we have the builtins, like so -

Median : [`scipy.signal.medfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt.html).

Max : [`scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter1d.html).

Min : [`scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter1d.html).

Mean : [`scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter1d.html)

Comment: Thanks again @Divakar

Answer (score 1):

The fact that applying of a median filter with the window size 1 will not change the array gives us a freedom to apply the median filter row-wise or column-wise.

For example, this code

```
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]])
median_filter(arr, size=3, cval=0, mode='constant')
#with cval=0, mode='constant' we set that input array is extended with zeros 
#when window overlaps edges, just for visibility and ease of calculation
```

outputs an expected filtered with window (3, 3) array

```
array([[0., 2., 0.],
       [2., 5., 3.],
       [0., 5., 0.]])
```

because median_filter automatically extends the `size` to all dimensions, so the same effect we can get with:

```
median_filter(arr, size=(3, 3), cval=0, mode='constant')
```

Now, we can also apply median_filter row-wise with setting 1 to the first element of `size`

```
median_filter(arr, size=(1, 3), cval=0, mode='constant')
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 2., 2.],
       [4., 5., 5.],
       [7., 8., 8.]])
```

And column-wise with the same logic

```
median_filter(arr, size=(3, 1), cval=0, mode='constant')
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```