# What is the numpy equivalent of pandas ewm().std()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the exponentially weighted rolling std of a time series using numpy. The equivalent in pandas would be `pd.DataFrame(ts).ewm(...).std()`. What's the way to go?

**Edit**

Possible solution:
https://pypi.org/project/numpy-ext/

where one could use npext.rolling_apply(...), apply weights on the rolling window and then do std().

Comment: @ChrisA It's similar, but I'm specifically looking for exponential weighted moving std instead of exp weighted moving average.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy version of "Exponential weighted moving average", equivalent to pandas.ewm().mean()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869495/numpy-version-of-exponential-weighted-moving-average-equivalent-to-pandas-ewm)

Comment: @kwinkunks that question is misleadingly titled since it is really asking for a high performance way of doing that.