# Vectorize a for loop over pandas ewm function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, iteration, vectorization

So I want to vectorize a for loop to speed things up. my code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def my_func(array, n):
    return pd.Series(array).ewm(span = n, min_periods = n-1).mean().to_numpy()

np.random.seed(0)
data_size = 120000

data = np.random.uniform(0,1000, size = data_size)+29000

loop_size = 1000
step_size = 1

X = np.zeros([data.shape[0], loop_size])
parameter_array = np.arange(1,loop_size+ step_size, step_size)

for i in parameter_array:
    X[:, i-1] = my_func(data, i)
```

The entire for-loop takes up about a min to finish, which could be a problem for future application. I have already checked the [numpy.vectorize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), but it states clearly that it is for convenience only, so using it won't speed up the code by an order of magnitude.

My question is that is there a way to vectorize the for loop like this? If so, can I see a simple example of how this can be done?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to figure out a way of doing that `ewm` for multiple values `n` with one call.

Comment: @hpaulj I haven't figured out just yet, which is another reason I post this question here. Maybe I should modify the title slightly.

Comment: See if this helps out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869495/

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for your reply. These new ema functions in that post answers work fine for arrays with the length below a certain number(I believe it is below 15k ish), but when the length is as big as my data's (120k), the outputs from these new ema functions will have a lot of inf. values at the tails. I think the reason for that is when length is big enough, the tail of the vector alpha**np.arange(length) will become zeros, due to having a lot of 1/0's