# NumPy version of “Exponential weighted moving average”, equivalent to TradingView RMA

Tags: python, numpy, tradingview-api

How do I get exponentially weighted moving average with `alpha = 1 / length` equivalent to RMA function in [TradingView RMA](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_rma) ?

I tried all functions mentioned in [NumPy version of "Exponential weighted moving average", equivalent to pandas.ewm().mean()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42869495/numpy-version-of-exponential-weighted-moving-average-equivalent-to-pandas-ewm/65606502#65606502) however can't match results to TradingView.

```
array
src = np.array([4086.29, 4310.01, 4509.08, 4130.37, 3699.99, 3660.02, 4378.48, 4640.0, 5709.99, 5950.02])
```

**with period = 3**

Should give results:

```
array([          nan,           nan, 4301.79333333, 4244.65222222,
       4063.09814815, 3928.73876543, 4078.65251029, 4265.76834019,
       4747.17556013, 5148.12370675])
```

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: could you please elaborate on exponential moving average formula?

Comment: It's here https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_rma

Comment: I already have looked at your previously provided link. It does not clearly provide the definition.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it matched with the following parameters using pandas:

```
window = 14
df['mean'] = df['close'].ewm(alpha = 1/window, min_periods = window, adjust = False).mean()
```