# Rolling maximum with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

This computes the "rolling max" of `A` (similar to rolling average) over a sliding window of length `K`:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(100000)
K = 10
rollingmax = np.array([max(A[j:j+K]) for j in range(len(A)-K)])
```

but I think it is far from optimal in terms of performance.

I know that the `pandas` library has [`rolling_max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_max.html), but in my project, I don't want to use this new dependance.

**Question: is there a simple way to compute the rolling maximum with numpy only?**

Comment: Note: This is *nearly* a duplicate of [Max in a sliding window in NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43288542/1422096) except that in that question, the max is on a window *around* the current point, and here it's a window *next* to the current point.

Comment: Computationally optimal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190184/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess this little trick using [`strides`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) and [`as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided) will do the job:

```
def max_rolling1(a, window,axis =1):
        shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
        strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
        rolling = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
        return np.max(rolling,axis=axis)
```

and for comaprison purpose I defined another function based on your algorithm :

```
def max_rolling2(A,K):
    rollingmax = np.array([max(A[j:j+K]) for j in range(len(A)-K)])
    return rollingmax
```

and the comparison by `timeit` on my laptop is :

with :

```
A = np.random.rand(100000)
K = 10


%timeit X = max_rolling2(A,K)
```

> ```
> 170 ms ± 19.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
> ```

```
%timeit X = max_rolling1(A,K)
```

> ```
> > 3.75 ms ± 479 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
> ```

Answer (score 6):

The solution is totally similar to [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43288787/1422096) here (full credit to him) but the final cropping of the array has different indices in this context:

```
maximum_filter1d(A, size=K)[K//2:-((K+1)//2)]
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter1d
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (50))
K = 5
rollingmax = np.array([max(A[j-K:j]) for j in range(K,len(A))])
rollingmax2 = np.array([max(A[j:j+K]) for j in range(len(A)-K)])
rollingmax3 = maximum_filter1d(A,size=K)[K//2:-((K+1)//2)]
print A, rollingmax, rollingmax2, rollingmax3
```

> [6 7 7 9 4 5 4 7 2 0 3 3 5 9 4 6 6 1 5 2 7 5 7 7 5 6 0 9 0 5 9 3 7 1 9 5 3
>    7 5 1 6 9 6 0 5 1 5 5 4 9]
>   [9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7 5 9 9 9 9 9 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 7 7
>    9 9 9 9 9 6 5 5]
>   [9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7 5 9 9 9 9 9 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 7 7
>    9 9 9 9 9 6 5 5]
>   [9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7 5 9 9 9 9 9 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 7 7
>    9 9 9 9 9 6 5 5]

Answer (score 0):

Just tested some of the code above, and it returns a few non expected results:

input:
test_array_input=np.array([1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 9, 7, 2, 4])

output with rolling max (above) yields: [ 1 3 4 5 4 9 7 2] when checking max over 2 fields, i.e. K=1

whereas would expect: [3 4 5 5 9 9 7 4] --> i,.e first field max of 1 & 3

I've implemented:

```
def udf_rolling_maximum_array(inputarray,numfieldsrolling):
    # example: input ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4)  -- 9 fields
    # example: rolling of 2 numfieldsrolling
    # example: output ( 2 3 4 5 6 6 3 4)   -- 8 fields
    # example: rolling of 3 numfieldsrolling
    # example: output (3 4 5 6 6 6 4) -- 7 fields
    import numpy as np
    # setup result array
    k=len(inputarray)-numfieldsrolling+1        
    rollingmax=np.empty(k)
    
    for i in range(k): rollingmax[i] = max(inputarray[i:i+numfieldsrolling])
        
    return rollingmax  #return rolling average array as output of UDF
```

The solutions given above rollingmax,rollingmax1,rollingmax2 in the original post failed my unit test - cf my expectations. See examples in the code text for behaviour I expected. I've not optimised my code for speed - as I dont'have huge data sets.

Answer (score -1):

Was happy to find these solutions - until I tried with large values for K.
Having an array of ~6M floats, K = 25000....takes very long

Comment: Did you find a better solution? Please post a complete answer (this is more a comment) if you find one.