# How to force a 1d signal to have 2 minimums?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, smoothing

I have a signal that looks like the blue one, and I want to obtain the red one, while knowing there are exactly 2 minimums within the range `(0, 255)`.

[image]

To obtain the red signal, I have done

```
@staticmethod
def _smooth_curve(curve, kernel_size=5):
    kernel = np.ones((kernel_size,)) / kernel_size
    smooth = np.convolve(curve, kernel, mode='same')
    return smooth

sig= self._smooth_curve(sig, 20)
sig= self._smooth_curve(sig, 14)
sig= self._smooth_curve(sig, 10)
sig= self._smooth_curve(sig, 6)
```

This is far from robust.

I want to make sure I get 2 minimums, and that they come out between the 3 peaks.

The peaks are not necessarily at the shown amplitudes, but they are separable, meaning they don't overlap in a way that finding minima makes no sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find peaks location in a spectrum numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656367/find-peaks-location-in-a-spectrum-numpy)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves)) of the signal would be a better start.

The idea is described [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11389/envelope-of-a-signal-via-convex-hull-edge-detection) and a function that you could use is [scipy.signal.hilbert()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html) .

You might have to apply a filter to the envelope, but it should be more robust.

On your comment with the minimum around 40: 
Then you need to use something like a max-pooling window or rolling maximum. That's like your convolution, but instead of sum and divide it does just max.

The idea is shown [here](https://peltarion.com/knowledge-center/documentation/modeling-view/build-an-ai-model/blocks/1d-global-max-pooling).

There is [scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html) which works on images. The docs state it's for multi-dimensions, so it might work on 1d arrays if you set the keyword `size` to maybe `3`.

There are also other possibilities that might be even easier

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218596/rolling-maximum-with-numpy/52219082) has nice solutions
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213863/numpy-version-of-rolling-maximum-in-pandas) mentiones pandas' `rolling` function which can be used with `max()` and [scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter1d.html)
- [And another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288542/max-in-a-sliding-window-in-numpy-array)

Of course it is also possible to combine envelope and rolling maximum.

Comment: On the above signel, an envelope would create a new minimum at around 40. I would get a smoother signel, but still how would I get the seperation I need?