# numpy create array of the max of consecutive pairs in another array

Tags: python, numpy, max-pooling

I have a numpy array:

```py
A = np.array([8, 2, 33, 4, 3, 6])
```

What I want is to create another array B where each element is the pairwise max of 2 consecutive pairs in A, so I get:

```py
B = np.array([8, 33, 33, 4, 6])
```

Any ideas on how to implement?
Any ideas on how to implement this for more then 2 elements? (same thing but for consecutive n elements)

### Edit:

The answers gave me a way to solve this question, but for the n-size window case, is there a more efficient way that does not require loops?

### Edit2:

Turns out that the question is equivalent for asking how to perform 1d max-pooling of a list with a window of size n.
Does anyone know how to implement this efficiently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A loop-free solution is to use `max` on the windows created by `skimage.util.view_as_windows`:

```
list(map(max, view_as_windows(A, (2,))))
```

```
[8, 33, 33, 4, 6]
```

Copy/pastable example:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

A = np.array([8, 2, 33, 4, 3, 6])

list(map(max, view_as_windows(A, (2,))))
```

Comment: This is a really nice feature of `skimage`. I'm also eager to understand does it work in terms of `numpy` methods if it's better than `O(len(A)*n)`.

Comment: Yes that would be interesting. Why don't you try it

Comment: I actually did it using `np.minimum.accumulate`. It helped me to gain some interesting insights. For example, I was able to make a list of checks whether `A[:k]` has minimum in `A[:k-n]` (where n is a fixed size of window and k is an iterable) in a vectorized way and linear time. But that was not sufficient to progress further with solution.

Answer (score 9):

One solution to the pairwise problem is using the [np.maximum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) function and array slicing:

```py
B = np.maximum(A[:-1], A[1:])
```

Answer (score 5):

In this Q&A, we are basically asking for sliding max values. This has been explored before - [Max in a sliding window in NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288542/max-in-a-sliding-window-in-numpy-array). Since, we are looking to be efficient, we can look further. One of those would be `numba` and here are two final variants I ended up with that leverage `parallel` directive that boosts performance over a without version :

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def numba1(a, W):
    L = len(a)-W+1
    out = np.empty(L, dtype=a.dtype)
    v = np.iinfo(a.dtype).min
    for i in prange(L):
        max1 = v
        for j in range(W):
            cur = a[i + j]
            if cur>max1:
                max1 = cur                
        out[i] = max1
    return out 

@njit(parallel=True)
def numba2(a, W):
    L = len(a)-W+1
    out = np.empty(L, dtype=a.dtype)
    for i in prange(L):
        for j in range(W):
            cur = a[i + j]
            if cur>out[i]:
                out[i] = cur                
    return out
```

From the earlier linked Q&A, the equivalent SciPy version would be -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter1d

def scipy_max_filter1d(a, W):
    L = len(a)-W+1
    hW = W//2 # Half window size
    return maximum_filter1d(a,size=W)[hW:hW+L]
```

#### Benchmarking

Other posted working approaches for generic window arg :

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

def rolling(a, window):
    shape = (a.size - window + 1, window)
    strides = (a.itemsize, a.itemsize)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

# @mathfux's soln
def npmax_strided(a,n):
    return np.max(rolling(a, n), axis=1)

# @Nicolas Gervais's soln
def mapmax_strided(a, W):
    return list(map(max, view_as_windows(a,W)))

cummax = np.maximum.accumulate
def pp(a,w):
    N = a.size//w
    if a.size-w+1 > N*w:
        out = np.empty(a.size-w+1,a.dtype)
        out[:-1] = cummax(a[w*N-1::-1].reshape(N,w),axis=1).ravel()[:w-a.size-1:-1]
        out[-1] = a[w*N:].max()
    else:
        out = cummax(a[w*N-1::-1].reshape(N,w),axis=1).ravel()[:w-a.size-2:-1]
    out[1:N*w-w+1] = np.maximum(out[1:N*w-w+1],
                            cummax(a[w:w*N].reshape(N-1,w),axis=1).ravel())
    out[N*w-w+1:] = np.maximum(out[N*w-w+1:],cummax(a[N*w:]))
    return out
```

Using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions.

```
import benchit
funcs = [mapmax_strided, npmax_strided, numba1, numba2, scipy_max_filter1d, pp]
in_ = {(n,W):(np.random.randint(0,100,n),W) for n in 10**np.arange(2,6) for W in [2, 10, 20, 50, 100]}
t = benchit.timings(funcs, in_, multivar=True, input_name=['Array-length', 'Window-length'])
t.plot(logx=True, sp_ncols=1, save='timings.png')
```

[image]

So, numba ones are great for window sizes lower than `10`, at which there's no clear winner and on larger window sizes `pp` wins with SciPy one at second spot.

Comment: For small arrays len < (500_000) the single threaded version is faster, for very small arrays much faster.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach specifically taylored for larger windows. It is O(1) in window size and O(n) in data size.

I've done a pure numpy and a pythran implementation.

How do we achieve O(1) in window size? We use a "sawtooth" trick: If w is the window width we group the data into lots of w and for each group we do the cumulative maximum from left to right and from right to left. The elements of any in-between window distribute over two groups and the maxima of the intersections are among the cumulative maxima we have computed earlier. So we need a total of 3 comparisons per data point.

benchit (thanks @Divakar) for w=100; my functions are pp (numpy) and winmax (pythran):

[image]

For small window size w=5 the picture is more even. Interestingly, pythran still has a huge edge even for very small sizes. They must be doing something right to mimimze call overhead.

[image]

python code:

```
cummax = np.maximum.accumulate
def pp(a,w):
    N = a.size//w
    if a.size-w+1 > N*w:
        out = np.empty(a.size-w+1,a.dtype)
        out[:-1] = cummax(a[w*N-1::-1].reshape(N,w),axis=1).ravel()[:w-a.size-1:-1]
        out[-1] = a[w*N:].max()
    else:
        out = cummax(a[w*N-1::-1].reshape(N,w),axis=1).ravel()[:w-a.size-2:-1]
    out[1:N*w-w+1] = np.maximum(out[1:N*w-w+1],
                            cummax(a[w:w*N].reshape(N-1,w),axis=1).ravel())
    out[N*w-w+1:] = np.maximum(out[N*w-w+1:],cummax(a[N*w:]))
    return out
```

pythran version; compile with `pythran -O3 <filename.py>`; this creates a compiled module which you can import:

```
import numpy as np

# pythran export winmax(float[:],int)
# pythran export winmax(int[:],int)

def winmax(data,winsz):
    N = data.size//winsz
    if N < 1:
        raise ValueError
    out = np.empty(data.size-winsz+1,data.dtype)
    nxt = winsz
    for j in range(winsz,data.size):
        if j == nxt:
            nxt += winsz
            out[j+1-winsz] = data[j]
        else:
            out[j+1-winsz] = out[j-winsz] if out[j-winsz]>data[j] else data[j]
    running = data[-winsz:N*winsz].max()
    nxt -= winsz << (nxt > data.size)
    for j in range(data.size-winsz,0,-1):
        if j == nxt:
            nxt -= winsz
            running = data[j-1]
        else:
            running = data[j] if data[j] > running else running
            out[j] = out[j] if out[j] > running else running
    out[0] = data[0] if data[0] > running else running
    return out
```

Comment: Not bad for a NumPy only version.

Answer (score 3):

In case there are consecutive `n` items, extended solution requires looping:

```
np.maximum(*[A[i:len(A)-n+i+1] for i in range(n)])
```

In order to avoid it you can use [stride tricks](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) and convert `A` to array of `n`-length blocks:

```
def rolling(a, window):
    shape = (a.size - window + 1, window)
    strides = (a.itemsize, a.itemsize)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

For example:

```
>>> rolling(A, 3)
array([[ 8,  2,  8],
   [ 2,  8, 33],
   [ 8, 33, 33],
   [33, 33,  4]])
```

After it's done you can kill it with `np.max(rolling(A, n), axis=1)`.

Though, despite its elegance, **neither this solution nor first one were not efficient** because we apply repeatedly maximum on adjacent blocks that differs by two items only.

Comment: any suggestions for how can we make this solution loop-free and efficient?
maybe vectorization of some kind can help?

Comment: It requires more efforts for working out. Something like `np.minimum.accumulate` might help.

Comment: @GalSuchetzky It seem's that we need a deeper understanding of algorithm of finding `min` in consecutive blocks - something that I can't find out on my own or internet. This is quite interesting question if we consider it in general case so I think it's worth to ask for experts and start a bounty on this question whenever this option is opened.

Answer (score 2):

a recursive solution, for all of n

```
import numpy as np
import sys


def recursive(a: np.ndarray, n: int, b=None, level=2):
    if n <= 0 or n > len(a):
        raise ValueError(f'len(a):{len(a)} n:{n}')
    if n == 1:
        return a
    if len(a) == n:
        return np.max(a)
    b = np.maximum(a[:-1], a[1:]) if b is None else np.maximum(a[level - 1:], b)
    if n == level:
        return b
    return recursive(a, n, b[:-1], level + 1)


test_data = np.array([8, 2, 33, 4, 3, 6])
for test_n in range(1, len(test_data) + 2):
    try:
        print(recursive(test_data, n=test_n))
    except ValueError as e:
        sys.stderr.write(str(e))
```

output

```
[ 8  2 33  4  3  6]
[ 8 33 33  4  6]
[33 33 33  6]
[33 33 33]
[33 33]
33
len(a):6 n:7
```

---

## about recursive function

You can observe the following data, and then you will know how to write the recursive function.

```
"""
np.array([8, 2, 33, 4, 3, 6])
n=2: (8, 2),     (2, 33),    (33, 4),    (4, 3),   (3, 6)  => [8, 33, 33, 4, 6] => B' = [8, 33, 33, 4]
n=3: (8, 2, 33), (2, 33, 4), (33, 4, 3), (4, 3, 6)         => B' [33, 4, 3, 6]  =>  np.maximum([8, 33, 33, 4], [33, 4, 3, 6]) => 33, 33, 33, 6
...
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Pandas`:

```
A = pd.Series([8, 2, 33, 4, 3, 6])
res = pd.concat([A,A.shift(-1)],axis=1).max(axis=1,skipna=False).dropna()

>>res
0     8.0
1    33.0
2    33.0
3     4.0
4     6.0
```

Or using numpy:

```
np.vstack([A[1:],A[:-1]]).max(axis=0)
```