# Is there a good way to do "moving" calculations on numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am working on a data processing project in which I would generally like to take a 1D numpy array as input, and output an equal length array who's elements were generated by processing a certain number of input elements. 
This is a relatively simple problem to solve using a for loop, but I am wondering if numpy has a built in way of doing this, which I assume would be significantly faster.

To illustrate my goals, imagine generating a vector (B) 1 element at a time, and let the current element being generated be element N (denoted B[N]).

Say I want B to be a vector whose elements correspond to a simple moving average of the elements in vector A.
What I want to be able to say is

```
B[i] = AVG(A[(i-N):i]) #N <= i < len(A)
```

Where i here is the iteration index of whatever underlying loop is running and AVG is a generic function which calculates the average of the group of numbers passed to it.

As I said, easy enough with a for loop, but this seems like a thing something like numpy should be able to do quite easily so I thought I'd ask the pros before I litter my code with less than optimal structures.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would require a specific example to answer.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão. That question has nothing to do with this one. OP is trying to step away from using raw Python and use numpy instead.

Comment: Have you played with functions like `np.cumsum` and `np.cumprod`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is the pseudo code not specific enough? I believe I was quite thorough in explanation of my goals. I'm only wondering if numpy has a built in way of doing what I did in the sudo code.

Comment: @hpaulj I have used cumsum for some applications but trying to use it with things that measure movement information (such as standard deviation) I think it doesn't really work.

Comment: Meant to say "pseudo" (noticed after 5 minutes), the terminal is getting to me.

Comment: If that operation is expressible as NumPy ufuncs, you could create sliding windows,  like shown [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085052/3293881) and then use those ufuncs along the last axis of the 2D array of sliding windows. If there's a specific operation that you are after, we could find better optimized ways.

Comment: @JoshWiens. My fault entirely. I misread: forgot to read the end of your sentence "which calculates the average of the group of numbers passed to it". I thought AVG was a placeholder for *any* function at all.

Comment: Couple of dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14313510/2988730, https://stackoverflow.com/q/13728392/2988730

Comment: By the way, did you mean `A[i-N:i+1]` in your question? The stop index is is exclusive.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13728392/52074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [standard moving window functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/api.html#standard-moving-window-functions) in Pandas. For example the moving average with window size 10 will be `pd.rolling_mean(data, window=10)`.

You can also provide your own aggregation function with `pd.rolling_apply(data, lambda x: np.mean(x), window=10)`, which is the same as the previous one.

Comment: While Pandas is definitely not off the table, right now I'm really specifically wondering about numpy. That does look like exactly what I want to do though in the end, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I am accepting this answer despite it not quite adhering to the initial question. @Mad Physicist's answer is a good solution for the specific question asked. But given a project where you would like apply a multitude of different process algorithms, this solution is drastically more applicable. Pandas is worth using for this function alone imo.

Answer (score 1):

A bit low-level, but you can filter the data by cross-correlating it with a window of your choosing. A moving average window is a bunch of ones divided by however many ones there are. Note that the correlate has various "modes" and the validity of the start/end points vary.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

window_size = 10
window = np.ones(window_size) / window_size
x = np.random.rand(100)

x_filt = signal.correlate(x, window, mode='same')

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x)
ax.plot(x_filt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest pure numpy solution that does not use convolution is the one using [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html). The basic idea is that the sum of elements from index `i - N` to index `i` (both inclusive) is the cumulative sum up to `i`, minus the cumulative sum up to `i - N - 1`. The normalization is just `N` itself:

```
s = np.cumsum(A)
B = (s[N:] - s[:-N]) / N
```

It is not clear if you want `B` to be the same length as `A`. If so, you could, for example, prepend the first `N` values of the cumulative sum to `B` using [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) or [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
B = np.concatenate((s[:N] / np.arange(N), (s[N:] - s[:-N]) / N))
```

OR

```
B = np.r_[s[:N] / np.arange(N), (s[N:] - s[:-N]) / N]
```

After writing this, I realized that @Jaime has a very similar answer to basically the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14314054/2988730). I am going to retain my answer because it correctly normalizes the initial portion of the array, which I am not convinced that Jaime's answer does.