# Extract subarrays from 1D array given start indices - Python / NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

NumPy arrays may be indexed with other arrays. To illustrate:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0et ], 'f4')
>>> ids = np.array([0, 2], 'i4')
arr[ids]
array([ 0.,  2.], dtype=float32)
```

But what if I wanted to have a multiarray with the value pointed by the index plus the three subsequents elements?

```
>>> arr[ids:(ids+4)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid slice
```

Expected:

```
array([[0. 1. 2. 3.], [2. 3. 4. 5.]], dtype=float32)
```

**How to make this possible?**

Comment: I think you either have one two many elements in each of the subarrays of the expected output or othewise you meant `arr[ids:(ids+4)]`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`broadcasted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) addition to create all those indices and then index -

```
all_idx = ids[:,None]+range(4) # or np.add.outer(ids, range(4))
out = arr[all_idx]
```

Using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`strided_app`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085052/) -

```
strided_app(arr, 4, S=1)[ids]
```