# Fast sequential lists for tensorflow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, array-broadcasting

I have an array `A` of matrices (or a 3-dim tensor) and I want to do the following:

Denote each matrix with a number, so `A` is `[1,2,3,4,...,]`, and let's say that we have a window of length 3, I want to pass as input to a TensorFlow graph the 4-dim array `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],....]`. What's the most efficient way of doing this? (It's a bit like a convolution with a constant kernel, but without summing over the resulting matrices).

At the moment this is what I'm doing:

```
input_NN = [data[t, t + window] for t in range(my_range)]
```

and then I pass it to a TF placeholder.

Shall I think of a better way of doing it in `numpy` and pass the result to a placeholder or is there a fast way of doing this in TensorFlow by passing `A` directly?

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, but my question is wider than the "duplicates": I'm asking if it's possible to implement this in TensorFlow.

Comment: Reopened. Curious - Can you index into the first axis of input tensor with those sliding indices that could be computed with the broadcasting app from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085052/?

Comment: I'm giving it a go now

Comment: Yes we can, but it's not faster than a for loop (at least for my array dimensions)

Comment: Are you looking for [`tf.extract_image_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_image_patches)?

Comment: @DanielF I used exactly that, works really well!