# How to compute moving (or rolling, if you will) percentile/quantile for a 1d array in numpy?

Tags: pandas, numpy, quantile, rolling-computation

In pandas, we have `pd.rolling_quantile()`. And in numpy, we have `np.percentile()`, but I'm not sure how to do the rolling/moving version of it.

To explain what I meant by moving/rolling percentile/quantile:

Given array `[1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 8, 10]`, the moving quantile `0.5` (i.e. moving percentile 50%) with window size 3 is:

```
1
5 - 1 5 7 -> 0.5 quantile = 5
7 - 5 7 2 ->                5
2 - 7 2 4 ->                4
4 - 2 4 6 ->                4
6 - 4 6 9 ->                6
9 - 6 9 3 ->                6
3 - 9 3 8 ->                8
8 - 3 8 10 ->               8
10
```

So `[5, 5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8]` is the answer. To make the resulting series the same length as the input, some implementation inserts `NaN` or `None`, while `pandas.rolling_quantile()` allows to compute the first two quantile values by a smaller window.

Comment: Can you show the sample data and expected out put ?

Comment: Just did. Hope this clarifies my goal. @Wen

Comment: check the answer :-)

Comment: Is that what you need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could create the sliding windows with `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`, implemented as a function as [`strided_app`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40085052/) -

```
In [14]: a = np.array([1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 8, 10]) # input array

In [15]: W = 3 # window length

In [16]: np.percentile(strided_app(a, W,1), 50, axis=-1)
Out[16]: array([ 5.,  5.,  4.,  4.,  6.,  6.,  8.,  8.])
```

To make it of the same length as the input, we could pad `NaNs` with `np.concatenate` or easier with `np.pad`. Hence, for `W=3`, it would be -

```
In [39]: np.pad(_, 1, 'constant', constant_values=(np.nan)) #_ is previous one
Out[39]: array([ nan,   5.,   5.,   4.,   4.,   6.,   6.,   8.,   8.,  nan])
```

Comment: Marked as answer since it provides a solution to my question. Just curious, can your method extend to do the `min_periods` bit of `pandas.rolling_quantile()` (i.e. to create two additional strides at the beginning, each with fewer members)?  @Divakar

Comment: @Roy Yup. Pad the input array with NaNs and use `np.nanpercentile`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @Divakar.

Comment: This approach can lead to memory overflow for large input arrays.

Answer (score 7):

```
series = pd.Series([1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 8, 10])

In [194]: series.rolling(window = 3, center = True).quantile(.5)

Out[194]: 
0      nan
1   5.0000
2   5.0000
3   4.0000
4   4.0000
5   6.0000
6   6.0000
7   8.0000
8   8.0000
9      nan
dtype: float64
```

Center is `False` by default. So you need to manually set it to `True` for the quantile-calculation window to embrace the current index symmetrically.