# Rolling comparison between a value and a past window, with percentile/quantile

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-analysis, moving-average

I'd like to compare each value `x` of an array with a rolling window of the n previous values. More precisely I'd like to see **at which percentile this new value `x` would be, if we added it to the previous window**:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1, 4, 9, 28, 28.5, 2, 283, 3.2, 7, 15])
print A
n = 4  # window width
for i in range(len(A)-n):
    W = A[i:i+n]
    x = A[i+n]
    q = sum(W <= x) * 1.0 / n
    print 'Value:', x, ' Window before this value:', W, ' Quantile:', q
```

> [   1.     4.     9.    28.    28.5    2.   283.     3.2    7.    15. ]
>   Value: 28.5  Window before this value: [  1.   4.   9.  28.]  Quantile: 1.0
>   Value: 2.0  Window before this value: [  4.    9.   28.   28.5]  Quantile: 0.0
>   Value: 283.0  Window before this value: [  9.   28.   28.5   2. ]  Quantile: 1.0
>   Value: 3.2  Window before this value: [  28.    28.5    2.   283. ]  Quantile: 0.25
>   Value: 7.0  Window before this value: [  28.5    2.   283.     3.2]  Quantile: 0.5
>   Value: 15.0  Window before this value: [   2.   283.     3.2    7. ]  Quantile: 0.75

Question: **What is the name of this computation? Is there a clever numpy way to compute this more efficiently on arrays of millions of items (with n that can be ~5000)?**

---

Note: here is a simulation for 1M items and n=5000 but it would take ~ 2 hours:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.random(1000*1000)  # the following is not very interesting with a [0,1]
n = 5000                         # uniform random variable, but anyway...
Q = np.zeros(len(A)-n)
for i in range(len(Q)):
    Q[i] = sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n]) * 1.0 / n
    if i % 100 == 0: 
        print "%.2f %% already done. " % (i * 100.0 / len(A))

print Q
```

Note: this is not similar to [How to compute moving (or rolling, if you will) percentile/quantile for a 1d array in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585465/how-to-compute-moving-or-rolling-if-you-will-percentile-quantile-for-a-1d-arr)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is so slow because you're using Python's own `sum()` instead of `numpy.sum()` or `numpy.array.sum()`; Python's `sum()` has to convert all the raw values to Python objects before doing the calculations, which is really slow. Just by changing `sum(...)` to `np.sum(...)` or `(...).sum()`, the runtime drops to under 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47588876/9274732) of the question you linked. With the first example you give, it is pretty easy to understand:

```
A = np.array([1, 4, 9, 28, 28.5, 2, 283, 3.2, 7, 15])
n=4
print (np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=(A.size-n,n),
                                       strides=(A.itemsize,A.itemsize)))
# you get the A.size-n columns of the n rolling elements
array([[  1. ,   4. ,   9. ,  28. ,  28.5,   2. ],
       [  4. ,   9. ,  28. ,  28.5,   2. , 283. ],
       [  9. ,  28. ,  28.5,   2. , 283. ,   3.2],
       [ 28. ,  28.5,   2. , 283. ,   3.2,   7. ]])
```

Now to do the calculation, you can compare this array to A[n:], `sum` over the rows and divide by `n`:

```
print ((np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=(n,A.size-n),
                                        strides=(A.itemsize,A.itemsize)) 
          <= A[n:]).sum(0)/(1.*n))
[1.   0.   1.   0.25 0.5  0.75] # same anwser
```

Now the problem is the size of you data (several M and n around 5000), not sure you can use directly this method. One way could be to chunk the data. Let's define a function

```
def compare_strides (arr, n):
   return (np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(n,arr.size-n),
                                           strides=(arr.itemsize,arr.itemsize)) 
            <= arr[n:]).sum(0)
```

and do the chunk, with `np.concatenate` and don't forget to divide by `n`:

```
nb_chunk = 1000 #this number depends on the capacity of you computer, 
                # not sure how to optimize it
Q = np.concatenate([compare_strides(A[chunk*nb_chunk:(chunk+1)*nb_chunk+n],n) 
                    for chunk in range(0,A[n:].size/nb_chunk+1)])/(1.*n)
```

I can't do the 1M - 5000 test, but on a 5000 - 100, see the difference in `timeit`:

```
A = np.random.random(5000)
n = 100

%%timeit
Q = np.zeros(len(A)-n)
for i in range(len(Q)):
    Q[i] = sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n]) * 1.0 / n

#1 loop, best of 3: 6.75 s per loop

%%timeit
nb_chunk = 100
Q1 = np.concatenate([compare_strides(A[chunk*nb_chunk:(chunk+1)*nb_chunk+n],n) 
                    for chunk in range(0,A[n:].size/nb_chunk+1)])/(1.*n)

#100 loops, best of 3: 7.84 ms per loop

#check for egality
print ((Q == Q1).all())
Out[33]: True
```

See the difference in time from 6750 ms to 7.84 ms. Hope it works on bigger data

Comment: Here [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=(len(A)-5,6), strides=(A.itemsize,A.itemsize))`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) creates a view, as a 2D matrix, with all the consecutive windows. It gives the exact same result than [`skimage.util.shape.view_as_windows(A, (6,))`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows). Do you know the precise and computational differences @Ben.T?

Comment: @Basj if you go see the code [source](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py#L106) of the link you gave, actually, the method from `skimage` use `as_strided` from `numpy` at the end, so it makes sense that the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.sum` instead of sum was already mentioned, so my only suggestion left is to additionally consider using pandas and its rolling window function, which you can apply any arbitrary function to:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.random.random(1000*1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(A)
n = 5000

def fct(x):
    return np.sum(x[:-1] <= x[-1]) * 1.0 / (len(x)-1)

percentiles = df.rolling(n+1).apply(fct)
print(percentiles)
```

Comment: Great solution too! It takes ~ 25 seconds for me for 1M items and n=5000, like with AleksiTorhamo's answer.

Comment: Nice to know. However, on my cell phone it looks like this approach introduces a performance drawback against your loop. But perhaps this can be balanced by immediately having all results in a dataframe ready for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Additional benchmark: comparison between [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135487/1422096) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135490/1422096):

```
import numpy as np, time

A = np.random.random(1000*1000)
n = 5000

def compare_strides (arr, n):
   return (np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(n,arr.size-n), strides=(arr.itemsize,arr.itemsize)) <= arr[n:]).sum(0)

# Test #1: with strides ===> 11.0 seconds
t0 = time.time()
nb_chunk = 10*1000
Q = np.concatenate([compare_strides(A[chunk*nb_chunk:(chunk+1)*nb_chunk+n],n) for chunk in range(0,A[n:].size/nb_chunk+1)])/(1.*n)
print time.time() - t0, Q

# Test #2: with just np.sum ===> 18.0 seconds
t0 = time.time()
Q2 = np.zeros(len(A)-n)
for i in range(len(Q2)):
    Q2[i] = np.sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n])
Q2 *= 1.0 / n  # here the multiplication is vectorized; if instead, we move this multiplication to the previous line: np.sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n]) * 1.0 / n, it is 6 seconds slower
print time.time() - t0, Q2

print all(Q == Q2)
```

There's also another (better) way, with `numba` and `@jit` decorator. Then it is much faster: **only 5.4 seconds**!

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit  # if you remove this line, it is much slower (similar to Test #2 above)
def doit():
    A = np.random.random(1000*1000)
    n = 5000
    Q2 = np.zeros(len(A)-n)
    for i in range(len(Q2)):
        Q2[i] = np.sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n])
    Q2 *= 1.0/n
    print(Q2)

doit()
```

When adding numba parallelization, it's even faster: **1.8 seconds!**

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

@jit(parallel=True)
def doit(A, Q, n):
    for i in prange(len(Q)):
        Q[i] = np.sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n])

A = np.random.random(1000*1000)
n = 5000
Q = np.zeros(len(A)-n)    
doit(A, Q, n)
```

Comment: if you want to use `np.sum`, you can even improve the speed by doing this way `Q = np.array([np.less_equal(A[i:i+n],A[i+n]).sum() for i in range(len(A)-n)],dtype=float)/n`

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T, I tried it and it takes ~ 17 seconds for me, great! How do you explain the 30% speed improvement in comparison with the loop + np.sum version?

Comment: of what I know, using a list comprehension directly in the creation of an array is faster than creating an empty array and then have to access it at each loop to change the value (accessing a value in an array takes time). The other reason is dividing by n the whole array and not each value is faster as the division is vectorized. It also seems that imposing the `dtype=float` when creating the array was faster than converting an array of `int` to `float` (memory reason?). using `np.less_equal` or `<=` was not a significant improve for me

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks for this, I edited the answer. I also tried with numba, look at the result ;)

Comment: That is a pretty good improvement compare to your original solution :)

Comment: @Ben.T ... and another x3 improvement thanks to numba parallelization ;)

Comment: ha ha always faster :) just by curiosity as I'm not familiar with Numba, would it be possible (and interesting) to use it on the solution with strides?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `np.quantile` instead of `sum(A[i:i+n] <= A[i+n]) * 1.0 / n`. That may be as good as it gets. Not sure if there really is a better approach for your question.

Comment: Are you sure it would give the same thing? I don't think so. `np.quantile(W, 50)` would give the **value** x such that W < x for p=50% of the values in W. Here I'm looking for the opposite: knowing x, I'm looking for p.

Comment: Yep you're right, sorry! `quantile` is in fact not the inverse of `percentile`, which in my haste I assumed. They are almost the same.