# Stack slices of numpy array from given indices

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm struggling to perform the below operation on a `numpy` vector.

I want to take `previous_n` samples from `vector` finishing at `indices`.

It's like I want to perform a [np.take](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) with slicing of the `previous_n` samples.

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np

vector = np.array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])

# number of previous samples
previous_n = 3

indices = np.array([ 5,  7, 12])
```

**result**

```
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "finishing at indices"?

Comment: @liliscent a `slice(value - previous_n, value)` for value in `indices`

Comment: Wrapping np.array around a list comprehension is competitive.

Comment: or broadcast [-2, -1, 0] against `indices` to create the index matrix.

Comment: Ok, let me try that. Ta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this seems to do what I want. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084931/taking-subarrays-from-numpy-array-with-given-stride-stepsize/40085052#40085052)

```
def stack_slices(arr, previous_n, indices):
    all_idx = indices[:, None] + np.arange(previous_n) - (previous_n - 1)
    return arr[all_idx]
```

---

```
>>> stack_slices(vector, 3, indices)
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: ups... I accidentally downvoted. My mistake. Is it possible to edit the answer so I can correct my mistake?