# Array into multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, repeat

(Python) I have the following array

`x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

and I want this one

```
x=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]
```

I used this function

```
def split(arr, size):
 arrs = []
 while len(arr) > size:
     pice = arr[:size]
     arrs.append(pice)
     arr   = arr[size:]
 arrs.append(arr)
 return arrs
```

But it only generates this

```
x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Comment: If looking for performance, use NumPy strides or `broadcasting` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084931/taking-subarrays-from-numpy-array-with-given-stride-stepsize

Comment: You have a simple error. Change `arr   = arr[size:]` to `arr   = arr[1:]`

Comment: You say `x` is an array, but show a list.  The code also generates lists.  Is this a list problem or a numpy array one?  I"m tempted to edit the tags, removing 'arrays', 'numpy' and 'split'

Comment: @pault is almost correct.  use `arr = arr[size-1:]`  I assume you're passing 2 for size.  You haven't defined the correct result for other values so it might not be correct in those cases.

Comment: @JeffLearman I am pretty sure it should not be `size-1` although I agree that OP didn't specify. `arr = arr[1:]` returns a similar type output for all values of size (ie, lists of the same length, values consecutive).

Comment: @pault: Perhaps you're right: it depends on what `size` is intended to mean.  `size-1` works when size is 2, and does *something* that might be meaningful when size is >2.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want to develop your own code and not use libraries or built-in functions.

Your code is fine.

There's just one simple mistake: change the slice index from `size` to `1` in this line `arr  = arr[size:]`, where `1` means `size - (size-1)`

```
def split(arr, size):
    arrs = []
    while len(arr) > size:
        pice = arr[:size]
        arrs.append(pice)
        arr  = arr[1:]
    arrs.append(arr)
    return arrs
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```

It also works for other sizes:

```
print split(x, 3)
print split(x, 4)

[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `split(x, 3)`, etc. It *happens* to work in this one specific case, but it's wrong.

Comment: you could simplify by noting that `size-(size-1) = 1`

Comment: No I mean the correct thing to do is to not use `size` at all in the slice. The code should be `arr = arr[1:]`. You want to slide the list over by 1 each time. It is independent of `size`.

Comment: @pault: Really? What's the semantics for `size`?  The author doesn't say.

Comment: @JeffLearman this exchange happened before you posted your comment which correctly pointed out that OP didn't specify. I stand by my interpretation of the problem, though I recognize that you have a valid point.

Answer (score 2):

loop your array with index, then put `[index : index+size]` as one element of new array.

The codes will be like:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
size = 2
print([x[index:index+size] for index in range(0, len(x)-size+1)])
size = 4
print([x[index:index+size] for index in range(0, len(x)-size+1)])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
[Finished in 0.189s]
```

or use zip() with size>1.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
size = 2
print( [item for item in zip( *[x[index:len(x)+index-1] for index in range(0, size)])])
size = 4
print( [item for item in zip( *[x[index:len(x)+index-1] for index in range(0, size)])])
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6)]
[Finished in 0.284s]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
def split(arr, size):
    return [x[i:i+size] for i in range(0,len(x)-size+1)]
```

Comment: This could be right, depending on what's meant by `size`, which the OP doesn't specify.  But it's very pythonic and shows the use of list comprehensions.  And it's fixable if something else is meant by `size`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [windowed()](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.windowed) function from the [more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module.

```
from more_itertools import windowed
x = list(windowed(x, 2))
```

You can install it using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

```
pip install more-itertools
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

answer = list(map(list, zip(a, a[1:])))

print(answer)
```

Comment: I don't want it to be a tuple, but arrays inside an array

Comment: @BeatrizOrozco: this produces lists inside lists, which your example shows as the expected output.  Tuples would be printed using parentheses, not square brackets.  It would need to be modified for `size` other than 2.

Comment: I fixed it, thnk you

Answer (score 0):

You can use fancy indexing when using NumPy. This will require x to be converted to a numpy array. You will also need to create an array of incidences labeled `ind` below

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
x = np.array(x)

ind = np.arange(len(x)-1)[:,None] + np.arange(2)

x[ind]

array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6]])
```