# efficient way to rebuild np.array based on a moving slicing of a np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a numpy array of x time-steps, t, of 17 variables. My goal is to rebuild the array by having every index include the 17 variables for t, t+1, t+2 and t+3. Thereby, increasing the number of variables from 17 to 68 for every index (4*17 variables). As I'll do this computation over a large dataset, I was wondering what the most efficient method for this would be.

Thanks!

Comment: [Taking subarrays from numpy array with given stride/stepsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084931/taking-subarrays-from-numpy-array-with-given-stride-stepsize)?

Comment: @Divakar... If you think OP can find his answer in the linked question.. then just flag this question.