# Extract multiple roi's from np array using indices ranges without loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a numpy array of shape 640 x 480: `np.ones((640, 480))`, and I have a min, max ranges for the rows, columns:

```
u_min=[497, 157, 493, 137, 567] 
v_min=[ 36,  46, 208, 412, 418] 
u_max=[502, 162, 498, 142, 572]
v_max=[41, 51 213, 417, 423]
```

I have tried:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.ones((640, 480))

u_min= np.array([497, 157, 493, 137, 567], dtype=np.int32)
u_max= np.array([502, 162, 498, 142, 572], dtype=np.int32)
v_min= np.array([36, 46, 208, 412, 418], dtype=np.int32)
v_max= np.array([41, 51, 213, 417, 423], dtype=np.int32)

rois = arr[u_min:u_max, v_min:v_max]
```

but I'm getting an error:

> `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

I want to slice the numpy array in vectorized manner without looping. can you please tell me how can I do that? thanks

Comment: This needs a [mcve].  Multiple 1d slices have been addressed in previous SO.  Unless you can write a advanced indexing array(s), some sort of loop is needed.

Comment: Please demonstrate the output that you would like to see. There are two different answers with two interpretations of your question. One creates a three-dimensional array from the 5x5 sub-arrays given in u,v. The other uses multiple slices to return a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @grey_ranger both solutions achieve the goal, the only issue is the loops

Comment: We read the 'no loops' even when you didn't bold it!  Do you want people to shut up unless they meet your criteria exactly.  You can't take slices with arrays; that's basic python and numpy.  Some sort of loop and concatenation is required, whether before doing the advanced indexing, or after normal slicing.

Comment: Another possibiliy would be to construct a (5,5) `lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`, and select 5 (or is it 25?) blocks from that.  No guarantee that will be faster, or meet your **no loops** criteria.

Comment: I'd mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992055/slicing-an-array-with-arrays, except that SO is a 1d case, not 2d.  Still the same issues apply.  I explore all known alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think fancy indexing covers this. Or if it does, then not through simple slices but explicit indices. Therefore the most efficient way will be

```py
rois = np.stack([a[ul:uh, vl:vh] for ul, uh, vl, vh
                 in zip(u_min, u_max, v_min, v_max)])
```

Note that this only works because your ROIs are all the same shape. I assume this is intentional.

Comment: See my answer for a way to use slicing in case the selections are not the same shape.

Comment: @grey_ranger As I see it, the individual slices would still need to have the same overall size. You still cannot have, for example one ROI being 6 x 5 pixels. Unless I'm missing something

Comment: There's an important difference between our answers, which may need to be cleared up by OP. I'm treating u_min/u_max as multiple slices on ax1, and the same for v on ax2, ending with a `(25,25)` 2-dim numpy array. You're selecting each 5x5 sub-array and stacking them to make a `(5,5,5)` 3-dim numpy array. It's not clear to me from the question which one OP is looking for.

Comment: @grey_ranger yeah, I was just about to write the same after getting confused trying to compare answers. Let's OP figure this out

Comment: @Homer512, Hi thanks for your answer, I have edited the title of my question to emphasize the **no loops** otherwise this problem can be solved in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right: you're trying to use multiple slices to get the combination of several sub-arrays. However, the `rois = arr[u_min:u_max, v_min:v_max]` is actually interpreted as `rois = arr[<list>:<list>, <list>:<list>]` which doesn't make sense to the Numpy array object. Instead, you're going to need the max and min values together as pairs, so they define a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/5037133) of the array.

Let's start by zipping the `u_min` and `u_max` values together. This will create a `tuple` of `slice` objects. Each slice determines a start and stop point when we index the numpy array (see the link above).

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.ones((640, 480))
u_min=[497, 157, 493, 137, 567] 
v_min=[ 36,  46, 208, 412, 418] 
u_max=[502, 162, 498, 142, 572]
v_max=[41, 51, 213, 417, 423]

u_slices = tuple(slice(u1, u2) for u1, u2 in zip(u_min, u_max))
v_slices = tuple(slice(v1, v2) for v1, v2 in zip(v_min, v_max))
```

It's important to note that the start value **is included** but the stop value **is not included!** If you want to include the stop value, change `u2` -> `u2 + 1` and `v2` -> `v2 + 1`in the lines above. Our slices are:

```
> u_slices

(slice(497, 502, None),
 slice(157, 162, None),
 slice(493, 498, None),
 slice(137, 142, None),
 slice(567, 572, None))
```

Next, we need a way to use multiple slices in the same call to our Numpy array. We'll use the [R tricks](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18601018/5037133).

```
> arr[np.r_.__getitem__(u_slices), :].shape

(25, 480)
```

This selected 25 rows (or 30 if you used `u2 + 1`). Because of the way Numpy handles multi-indexing, we need to use `, :]` at the end of our selection. This tells Numpy we want just the given `u_slices` from axis 0 and all of axis 1. After we do this selection, we can do another selection on axis 1 using the `v_slices. Our final result:

```
> result = arr[np.r_[u_slices], :][: , np.r_[v_slices]]
> result.shape

(25, 25)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you call `__getitem__(u_slices)`. From my understanding of operators, it should be equivalent to `[u_slices]` and when I try it, the result is the same. So the final line should be equivalent if you write `arr[np.r_[u_slices], np.r_[v_slices]]`

Comment: Good point, I may have complicated it too far. I needed to use `__getitem__` for an earlier attempt, but no longer. I'll edit to compensate.

Comment: I think your fix broke the code. `arr[np.r_[u_slices], :][: , np.r_[v_slices]]` is not the same result as before. Checked with a random array and subtracting both results. It needs to be one `[]` as in my comment

Comment: @grey_ranger, Hi thanks for your answer, I have edited the title of my question to emphasize the **no loops** otherwise this problem can be solved in different ways.