# Iterating a numpy array in chunks

Tags: python, function, numpy, memory, numpy-ndarray

How can I arrange `list_` into groups of numbers using the `numpy.where()` or the `numpy.select()`. I want to break the data into groups of 3 and then calculate the standard deviation `std()` of those functions. So the program will take in `457.334015,424.440002,394.795990` for the first values of standard dev to be calculated and the will take `424.440002,394.795990, 408.903992` and calculate the standard deviation etc. It will keep on going like this till the end it reaches the end of the `list`. I want the first chunk  `457.334015,424.440002,394.795990` to be deleted before it calculates the second chunk `424.440002,394.795990, 408.903992`. I want to delete chunks from the memory so i do not have a memory error. Would this be possible with numpy and without using a for loop.

```
number = 3
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the number of values in the array will be in multiples of `number=3`?

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186869/numpy-stride-tricks-as-strided-vs-list-comprehension-for-rolling-window):

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
def strided_app(a, L, S ):  # Window len = L, Stride len/stepsize = S
    nrows = ((a.size-L)//S)+1
    n = a.strides[0]
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(nrows,L), strides=(S*n,n))
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])
np.std(strided_app(list_, 3, 1), axis=1)
```

However, this code does not delete any elements from the array. Also, keep in mind that the function used here comes with a [warning](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) from the numpy docs!

Comment: While this is correct, where does the rolling window approach you presented here remove the items from memory as the OP asked?

Comment: I want to separate the list into chunks and then calculate the standard deviation one by one