# How to extract the specific row and make that into new matrix?

Tags: numpy, matrix, extract

Here is my question.

There is a matrix call 'dt'.

What I want to do is make new matrix with same dt[:,0].

Below example will be helpful to understand what I want to do.

ex.

```
dt = [[0,0,0,0]
      [0,0,1,444]
      [0,0,2,80]
      [0,0,3,5]
      [1,0,0,0]
      [1,0,1,444]
      [1,0,2,80]
      [1,0,4,75]
      [2,1,2,653]
      ...
      ]]


new_matrix_0 =
     [[0,0,0,0]
      [0,0,1,444]
      [0,0,2,80]
      [0,0,3,5]]

new_matrix_1 = 
    [[1,0,0,0]
     [1,0,1,444]
     [1,0,2,80]
     [1,0,4,75]]
```

I need a code between 'dt' >> 'new_matrix_()'.

Thanks.

Comment: use `np.where` to achieve the split

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paritition array into N chunks with Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406567/paritition-array-into-n-chunks-with-numpy)

Comment: I believe OP wants to split the array based on value of first column, if we look at the variable names they are explicit `new_matrix_0` for value `0` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through `dt` and append the new matrix to a list.

```py
def get_new_matrices(dt):
    new_matrices = []
    n_rows = len(dt)
    i = 0
    while i < n_rows:
        new_matrices.append(dt[:][i:i+4])
        i = i + 4
    new_matrices.append(dt[:][i-4:n_rows])
    return new_matrices


dt = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6, 7],
      [0, 1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6, 7],
      [0, 1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6, 7],
      [0, 1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6, 7]]
new_mats = get_new_matrices(dt)
```

You can also use `np.array_split`

```
dt = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6, 7],
      [0, 1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6, 7],
      [0, 1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6, 7],
      [0, 1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6, 7]]
n = len(dt)
x = np.array(dt)
new_mats = np.array_split(x, int(n/4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the array into subarrays according to values in first column you can use [`split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) on indices where the values in the first column change. These indices can by found by [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and [`argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
dt = [[0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,1,444],
      [0,0,2,80],
      [0,0,3,5],
      [1,0,0,0],
      [1,0,1,444],
      [1,0,2,80],
      [1,0,4,75],
      [2,1,2,653]]
a = np.array(dt)
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(a[:,0])) + 1
np.split(a, idx.flat)
```

Result:

```
[array([[  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   1, 444],
        [  0,   0,   2,  80],
        [  0,   0,   3,   5]]),
 array([[  1,   0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   0,   1, 444],
        [  1,   0,   2,  80],
        [  1,   0,   4,  75]]),
 array([[  2,   1,   2, 653]])]
```

---

(if you, however, just want to get the rows where the first column is equal to `x` then it's simply `a[a[:,0]==x]`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dt` has `4*n`, then you can split it in `n` arrays with [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
>>> dt
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   1, 444],
       [  0,   0,   2,  80],
       [  0,   0,   3,   5],
       [  1,   0,   0,   0],
       [  1,   0,   1, 444],
       [  1,   0,   2,  80],
       [  1,   0,   4,  75],
       [  2,   1,   2, 653],
       [  4,   2,   1,   8],
       [ 10,  11,  21,   3],
       [  8,   5,   9,   1]])

>>> np.split(dt, len(dt)//4)
[array([[  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   1, 444],
        [  0,   0,   2,  80],
        [  0,   0,   3,   5]]), 

 array([[  1,   0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   0,   1, 444],
        [  1,   0,   2,  80],
        [  1,   0,   4,  75]]), 

  array([[  2,   1,   2, 653],
        [  4,   2,   1,   8],
        [ 10,  11,  21,   3],
        [  8,   5,   9,   1]])]
```