# How to split the numpy array into separate arrays in python. The number is splits is given by the user and the splitting is based on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles, binary-data, file-read

I want to split my numpy array into separate arrays. The separation must be based on the index. The split count is given by the user.

For example,
The input array:  `my_array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

If user gives split count =2,
then, the split must be like

```
my_array1=[1,3,5,7,9]
my_array2=[2,4,6,8,10]
```

if user gives split count=3, then
the output array must be

```
my_array1=[1,4,7,10]
my_array2=[2,5,8]
my_array3=[3,6,9]
```

could anyone please explain, I did for split count 2 using even odd concept

```
for i in range(len(outputarray)):
    if i%2==0:
        even_array.append(outputarray[i])  
    else:
        odd_array.append(outputarray[i])
```

I don't know how to do the split for variable counts like 3,4,5 based on the index.

Comment: Checkout: [Partition array into N chunks with Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406567/partition-array-into-n-chunks-with-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use indexing by vector (aka [fancy indexing](https://betterprogramming.pub/numpy-illustrated-the-visual-guide-to-numpy-3b1d4976de1d#c75a)) for it:

```
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
>>> n = 3
>>> [a[np.arange(i, len(a), n)] for i in range(n)]

[array([ 1,  4,  7, 10]), array([2, 5, 8]), array([3, 6, 9])]
```

**Explanation**

`arange(i, len(a), n)` generates an array of integers starting with `i`, spanning no longer than `len(a)` with step `n`. For example, for `i = 0` it generates an array

```
 >>> np.arange(0, 10, 3)
 array([0, 3, 6, 9])
```

Now when you index an array with another array, you get the elements at the requested indices:

```
 >>> a[[0, 3, 6, 9]]
 array([ 1,  4,  7, 10])
```

These steps are repeated for i=1..2 resulting in the desired list of arrays.

Comment: could you please explain how the loop works @Antony Hatchkins

Comment: could you please explain how to write the separated array in separate text files @Antony Hatchkins

Comment: Something along the lines of `for i, r in enumerate(res): np.savetxt(f'array{i}.txt', r)`

Comment: I've added an explanation of how the loop works

Comment: Is there any other way to save the separated array in separate text file as the np.save() saves each element as float values with one line space. The actual requirement is to save the separated array integers in the separate file with one tab space between each element. Could You please mention any other way of writing into the file @Antony Hatchkins

Comment: It is , `..., fmt='%d', newline='\t')` but you could as well find the docs for `np.savetxt` on the net or press shift-tab in jupyter to read it right in the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python-only way of doing your task

```
def split_array(array, n=3):
    arrays = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    for x in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            arrays[i] = [array[x] for x in range(len(array)) if x%n==i]
    return arrays
```

Input:

```
my_array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(split_array(my_array, n=3))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: could you please explain arrays[i] = [array[x] for x in range(len(array)) if x%n==i] @Mushfirat Mohaimin